# Unable to trigger jenkins job upon svn post-commit hook

Tags: svn, jenkins, triggers, post-commit, post-commit-hook

I am trying to trigger a jenkins job upon svn post-commit hook. 
But, I am getting below errors:
my jenkins is in windows at ###.###.1.7:8080
job is at : //###.###.1.7:8080/job/hooks_test/
I have also configured SCM POLL for every 2 mins.

ERROR MESSAGE:

Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
svnlook: Expected FS format '2'; found format '6'
svnlook: Expected FS format '2'; found format '6'

--2014-10-18 13:37:00--  //###.###.1.7:8080/subversion//notifyCommit?rev=51
Connecting to ###.###.1.7:8080... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-10-18 13:37:00 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Please help

===========

Server side post-commit :

`REPOS="$1" REV="$2" UUID=svnlook uuid $REPOS`
`/usr/bin/wget \`   
--header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \  
--post-data "svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS" \    
--output-document "-" \ --timeout=2 \  
//###.###.1.7:8080/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV  `

Comment: This is script I am using at svn server side:  REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`
/usr/bin/wget \
  --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
  --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
  --output-document "-" \
  --timeout=2 \
  http://###.###.1.7:8080/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV

Answer (score 1):

You have two **big and obvious** problems:

- "Expected FS format '2'; found format '6'" means, in plain words "Version of your SVN CLI-tools are old as mammoth's bullshit, but repository created with newer version and SVN can't handle it". Namely - FS format 2 is Subversion 1.4, format 6 - Subversion 1.8. Update your Subversion (better), or migrate repositories into another repositories, created with `svnadmin create --pre-1.6-compatible` (worse)
- "Connecting to ###.###.1.7:8080. 404 Not Found" is also clear - you tried to connect to URL `/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit` and this path not found on server (while http server working), because you have not uuid from svnlook - see at URL `/subversion//notifyCommit` *carefully*